# Unable to read nagios exit status in nagios core

Tags: nagios

I am using a command to throw a specific exit status when error count in one of my log files exceed a certain limit. Command is as follows:

`cd /home/serveradmin/logs/ | ls -trc | grep gateway | tail -1 | xargs cat | grep error | wc -l | awk '{if($1 >= "35000"){print "Critical: ",$1;exit 2} else if ($1 >= "25000") {print "Warning: ",$1;exit 1} else {exit 0} }'`

After executing the command, I have verified the exit status (my command returns exit code 1, because error count in my file is greater than 25000) with the following command:

`echo $?`

The above command returns 1 as output.

In my nrpe.cfg file I have defined the same command as follows:

`command[Error_Count]=cd /home/serveradmin/logs/ | ls -trc | grep gateway | tail -1 | xargs cat | grep error | wc -l | awk '{if($1 >= "35000"){exit 2} else if ($1 >= "25000") {exit 1} else {exit 0} }'`

I have defined the service in nagios core as follows:

```
define service {
        host_name               test_vm
        service_description     Error_Count
        check_command           check_nrpe!Error_Count
        use generic-service
        check_interval          1
}
```

After defining the service, nagios core is unable to read the exit status from the defined command in the nrpe.cfg file at client's end.

The error in my nagios dashboard returns an unknown status:[image]

Comment: following Nagios documentation page for [NRPE: Unable To Read Output](https://support.nagios.com/kb/article/nrpe-nrpe-unable-to-read-output-620.html), what troubleshooting have you already done? If you recall the script from command line, what's the output? Have you checked that all the permissions for your command are properly configured to be executed via NRPE?

Answer (score 1):

As [NRPE » Troubleshooting » Common Problems -- Unable To Read Output](https://support.nagios.com/kb/article/nrpe-nrpe-unable-to-read-output-620.html) says:

> This error implies that NRPE did not return any character output.

Your command exits with various status codes (2, 1, or 0), but it does not emit any actual output.

From https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/pluginapi.html, the "Plugin Output Spec" says:

> At a minimum, plugins should return at least one of text output.

See red highlighting there, indicating the required "text output".

Adjust your `awk` code to emit some sort of output in the various conditions:

```bsh
awk '{
  if($1 >= "35000")
    { print "Greater than or equal to 35000"; exit 2} 
  else if ($1 >= "25000") 
    { print "Greater than or equal to 25000"; exit 1} 
  else 
    { print "Less than 25000"; exit 0} 
  }'
```

Comment: The shortest way is to just replace your existing awk script with the one in the Answer, after you confirm it's appropriate for your environment.